# White color is complete Yellow on iPhone4?

Tags: ios, objective-c

On simulator,setting a background to be white , i get it white on all devices in simulator .
On actual device `iPhone 4` , its Yellow. Not a little bit, but a complete Yellow color .

I have read here about different colors on different devices, but there wasn't a single solution to this simple issue-  i can't make a white color on the device . Its not a similar color but a complete different one .

```
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
   self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor]; //or this
```

Comment: Show two screenshot snippets - one from your iPhone 4 and another from a device/simulator showing the proper color.

Comment: Are other colors distorted as well?  If you make a blue button or a red label, are those rendered accurately?

Comment: So there is something wrong with blue channel on your iPhone 4.

Comment: No. actually no other color is distorted .If i am trying to not setting any colour its also Yellow. I have clean all code, and left only this, but its still Yellow. In another view controller of mine, i am setting white- and its actually white . I dont know whats wrong with this specific view but i have check it all .

Comment: To rule out an hardware issue, try adding a friend's iPhone UDID to your development account and deploy the application to that device. See if you get the same result.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try that. I have also tried now to set it to be black- its still yellow . Seems that its this specific view, that is the open view of the program.

Comment: iPhone screens with odd color rendering is an pretty well documented phenomenon. If you bought the device recently, you may be able to get Apple to replace it. If not, you can try jailbreaking and using a color-calibration tool to adjust it.

Comment: Is this an iPhone 4, not a 4s? The 4 is pretty "long in the tooth" by today's standards. It won't run the current OS version, (iOS 8) for example.

Comment: If you take a screenshot and open that screenshot on your computer, does the view have a full white background colour or full yellow?